# What's the name of those threads at the edge of cloths?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

Some clothes (especially shawls) have at the edge kind of decorative part (see the picture attached here) of which kind of threads falls down.

What is called?

N.b. I don't know its name in my native language, otherwise, I'd check the dictionary.

[image], [image]

Comment: They might be tassels

Answer (score 3):

There may be other words, but it's a fringe:

[Google "fringed scarf"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=fringed%20scarf)

Answer (score 2):

Individually each one is a *tassel*

Collectively the line of tassels is a *fringe*.

https://feltmagnet.com/textiles-sewing/Knitting-Hints-How-to-Make-and-Attach-Fringe-Tassels-to-a-Scarf-Shawl-or-Sweater

Comment: A tassel has a knot at one end; if that is not present, the elements of a fringe are called something else, e.g. twists, threads, or strips.